# How can I use "getarchives_where" to get monthly archives for static pages?

Tags: pages, customization, archives

I would like to get monthly archives for static pages. I tried to use the next code:

```
add_filter('getarchives_where','my_archives_filter');
function my_archives_filter($where_clause) {
return "WHERE post_type = 'page' AND post_status = 'publish'";
}
```

and in the sidebar I write:

```
add_filter('getarchives_where','my_archives_filter');               
wp_get_archives('type=yearly');
remove_filter ('getarchives_where','my_archives_filter');
```

But it doesn't work.

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`wp_get_archives` already have `post_type = 'post'` by default and to replace it try this:

```
add_filter('getarchives_where','my_archives_filter');
function my_archives_filter($where_clause) {
    str_replace( "post_type = 'post'" , "post_type = 'page'" , $where );
}
```

in sidebar:

```
add_filter('getarchives_where','my_archives_filter');               
wp_get_archives('type=yearly');
remove_filter ('getarchives_where','my_archives_filter');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now in sidebar I get yearly archive but it gives me a 404 error when I follow de link (http://www.thedomain.com/2012)

Comment: That is beacuse the archive template is set to show posts and not pages

Comment: And how can I change it?

Answer (score 1):

The `add_filter` followed by `remove_filter` approach seems hacky, I prefer using a conditional approach like this:

```
/**
 * Post type archives by month
 */
function kevinlearynet_getarchives_events( $sql_where, $r ) {

    // conditions for when you want to do this
    // (don't do it all the time)
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'event' ) ) {
        $sql_where = str_replace( "post_type = 'post'" , "post_type = 'event'" , $sql_where );
    }

    return $sql_where;
}
add_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'kevinlearynet_getarchives_events', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to change the post_type to page, you do not need to use the filter. Just do the following:

```
wp_get_archives( array(
'post_type' => 'page'
) );
```

The problem with this is that the archives is geared toward posts not pages.

Answer (score 0):

wp_get_archives(array('post_type' => 'product',
'type' => 'monthly'
));